# cassandra schema data design for many-to-many array relationship

Tags: nosql, cassandra, schema, bigdata

So I need a DB that can store info for about 300 million users.  Each user will have two vectors:  their 5 favorite items, and their 5 most similar users (these users also contained in the user set)

ex:

```
preferences                  users

user  |  item           user  |  user  
--------------          --------------
user1 |  item1          user1 |  user2
user1 |  item2          user1 |  user4
user1 |  item3          user2 |  user8
user2 |  item3             .   .   .
user2 |  item4
.    .   .
```

So basically I need two tables, both many-many relationships, and both relatively big.
Ive been exploring cassandra (but im open to other solutions) and I was wondering how I would define the schema, and what type of indexing I need for this to be optimized and working properly.

I will need to query in two fashions:

1.By user of course, and 
  
2. by whatever item is in their list. 
           (so i can get a list of users with the same favorite item)

Ive already set up cassandra and started messing with it but I cant even get lists to work because i need 'composite' primary keys?  I dont understand why.

Any help/a push in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure you've adequately described your use case.  It is the access patterns that first and foremost define your key design, which is ultimately what defines your workload characteristics with NoSQL databases.  For example, are you going to have to do searches for users based on a certain geography or something along those lines or is this just simple , grab 1 user and his favorite items and/or his similar users.

Based on what you've described, you should probably just create a keyspace for user_ids and then your value can be the denormalized copies of "favorite items" and a list of "similar user id's".   Assuming your next action is to do something with those similar users, you can quickly get them from the list of id's.

The important point is how big is your key ( i mean in characters / bytes ) and will you be able to fit them into memory so you get really fast performance.  If your machines have limited memory for your key size, then you need to plan for a number of nodes which can accommodate a given number of keys and let those nodes run on separate servers.  At least that is the most important part for Oracle NoSQL Database (ONDB) .... I am part of that team.  Good news is that 300M is still very small.

Hope it helps,

-Robert

Comment: ..uh... reading my own post realize its a bit unclear.  ONDB has major-minor key implementation, so all minor portions are clustered locally to major keyspace.  So you want  user_id-favorite and user_id-similar as keys.  Then you can get at either or both values efficiently.  Important point is to pick a good user_id keyspace to get good distribution.